.net 8 web.config changes during azure devops pipeline deploy
In a .net 8 website, i want to restrict users from browsing to pdfs in a folder.
So i manually added a web.config with a location tag that restricts users who aren't authenticated.  It works, however when i deploy the site through azure devops pipeline, the web.config gets modified to add the aspnetcore processpath. When that happens, it is merging the aspnetcore config with the custom location tag i created. This causes a 404 when browsing the site.
How can i add the location tag without it interfering with the aspnetcore tag that is generated during the build process?
When i add this code in the web.config it does what i want:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="media/AppBuilder">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
</configuration>

However, when i then deploy the code in azure devops pipeline, the web.config gets changed to below which causes a 404:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="media/AppBuilder">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ClearSpringLife.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>

I then have to manually update it like this to fix:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="media/AppBuilder">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <deny users="?" />
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
<location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\ClearSpringLife.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>

